# Compositum of Hilbert class fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

For two given fields $K$ and $L$. Is the compositum of the hilbert class fields $H(K)$ and $H(L)$, equal to the Hilbert class field of the compositum $KL$?

Comment: Sounds unlikely: surely we could have $h_{KL}>h_K h_L$ say?

Comment: According to sage $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}, \sqrt{33}]$ is not a PID while $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{33}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$ both are. I think that answers the question. Sorry.

Comment: It is not a PID so what ? And is $H(K)H(L)/KL$ abelian ?

Comment: No the compositum of the Hilbert class field is no longer the Hilbert class field of the compositum.

Answer (score 2):

The fields $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-2})$ and $L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-163})$ have class number one, which implies that in this case $H(K)=K$ and $H(L)=L$ so that $H(K)H(L)=KL$. But their compositum $KL=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-163})$ has class number $3$ so we have $$[H(KL):H(K)H(L)]=[H(KL):KL]=3$$

so in this case the compositum of $H(K)$ and $H(L)$ cannot be equal to $H(LK)$ because it is too small.

Proof by Sage:
[image]